# How can I move the text position downwards using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to move the text "Hi" downwards because the PNG file makes it separate too much from the rest of the text.

```css
body {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.content     {
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    padding-left: 100px
}

.content > h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<article id="main" class="content">

      <h1>Hi, <br/> 
        I'm <img src="../Sources/Untitled-2.png" alt="V">ictor, 
        <br/> just another Video Editor.
      </h1>

</article>
```

Comment: I don't think you should be using `<h1>` for that - that's more of a `<p>`.

Comment: Add an image snip to let us know more about what you want to achieve, How low or how high :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<p>` tag to your "Hi," to be able to refer to that part of the text only. In this case, I added a class as well `<p class="hiText">Hi, </p>`.

Then in the CSS, I referred to the `hiText` class and applied the following properties: 
`position: absolute;` *This sets the position of the text to absolute.* 
`padding-top: -40px;` *This moves the text downwards. You can change 40px to any desired number and/or measurement unit.*

Hope this answers your question!

```css
body {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.content     {
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    padding-left: 100px
}

.content > h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.hiText {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: -40px;
 }
```

```html
<article id="main" class="content">

      <h1><p class="hiText">Hi, </p><br/> 
        I'm <img src="../Sources/Untitled-2.png" alt="V">ictor, 
        <br/> just another Video Editor.
      </h1>

</article>
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. A `<h1>` element **cannot contain a `<p>` element** - browsers will treat a nested `<p>` in a `<h1>` as a sibling of `<h1>`. If you look at the DOM you'll see the browser will break it up into `<h1></h1><p></p><h1></h1>`. See the documented "Permitted content" is "Phrasing content" on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

Comment: I agree that it's not the most optimal way to resolve this. However, I provided a solution based on the contextualization that the OP was seeking.

Answer (score -1):

I put "Hi," in a `<p class="hiText">   </p>` and then used

```
.hiText {
    position: relative;
    top: 38px;
}
```